# Bias of a Particular Estimator

Tags: statistics

Take $X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \mathrm{Gamma}(0,\theta)$ And take $\hat{\theta} =
\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. I want to try to find the bias of this estimator.
I can see that $\operatorname{bias}(\hat{\theta}) = \theta - E[\hat{\theta}],$
and we see that
$$E[\hat{\theta}] = \int aP(\hat{\theta} \leq a)\, da
= \int_ aP(\bigcap_{i \in [n]} X_i \leq a)\, da$$
$$= \int a\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_i \leq a) \,da,$$
where I see that $P(X_i \leq a) = F_{X_i}(a),$ i.e. the $\mathrm{Gamma}(0,\theta)$ CDF.
However, I understand that the CDF of a Gamma distribution is generally
intractable, so I thought of dealing with thigs using a PDF integral. However,
I am worried that I am approaching a rabbit-hole with this problem if I use
this mechanism, given that I don't even know the bounds of the outer integral
for calculating the expectation in this problem. Any recommendations on this?

Comment: What do you mean by a Gamma$(0,\theta)$ distribution?  As far as I know, $0$ does not make sense for any parameter (shape, scale or rate) of the Gamma distribution.

Comment: I'm GUESSING that you mean the distribution $e^{-x/\theta}\,dx$ on $x>0$.  But that's just a guess.  I don't think that gives you an intractable problem.  If you have $$\left( \frac x \theta \right)^\alpha e^{-x/\theta} \, \frac{dx} x \cdot \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \qquad \text{on } x>0,$$ and you need to estimate $\alpha$, _then_ you have to resort to numerical methods to get the MLE.  But if you know $\alpha$ and only need to estimate $\theta$, then you get a neat solution.  Also, if you use the method of moments, it's tractable, and then you can use that as a$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$first approximation when you apply Newton's method to the likelihood equation. $\qquad$